# Firebase/pyre base accessing multiple nodes all at once?

Tags: python, pyrebase

I was wondering if anyone had a solution for accessing multiple nodes and returning their key-value pairs at one time.

Say there is a list of all the node names I want to access, is there a way to do so without using a for loop? The for-loop method takes too long. being around 0.13 per request to firebase and I'm processing about 1000 nodes on a flask backend so efficiently is important